# Number to words in Rave Report

Tags: delphi, numbers, rave-reports

I have managed to design a report the way I want, but I am not able to get Rave Report to print/convert Grand total to Words.

For example, if the grand total is `1,200.00` it should only print `One Thousand and Two Hundred`.

Is something like this possible in Rave Report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think Rave Reports has any inbuilt function which converts numbers to works.  However, I have found a article, which explains [How to Convert Numbers (Currency) to Words](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/curr2words.htm), on About.com.

Have a look at the **ConvertToWords** function in the **NumberToWords** unit.

You could convert the number and pass the words to the report at runtime.

**Edit:**

You can pass parameters to your reports like this.

```
  RvProject.Open;
  RvProject.SelectReport('ParametrizedReport',False);
  RvProject.SetParam('Name','Leonel');
  RvProject.Execute;
  RvProject.Close;
```

Have a look at the [Introduction to Rave Reports](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/30331/) article.

Comment: Thanks for this link.
How do I set text in a Rave Report from Delphi code?

I don't know of any way by which I can manipulate content of a Rave Report when it is rendering or after it has rendered a page.

Comment: I have expanded my answer with an example of how to pass parameters to a rave report.